# Will chocolate eggs inside a cupcake melt when baked in the oven?

Tags: baking, chocolate, cupcakes

Easter is coming and I was interested in baking some cupcakes with a solid/praline-filled chocolate surprise inside. Please refer to the image below. Little side note: I will put smaller chocolate eggs inside and don't want them to be visible, they will be totally covered by cupcake batter, as opposed to being as you see them in the image.

I was wondering: if you put chocolate eggs inside the cupcake dough and let it bake in the oven, will they melt? And how badly?

If it's possible to avoid melting, how? Do I need to freeze the eggs first? Will any kind of chocolate egg do? (I was planning on solid/praline-filled eggs.)

I was hoping for some advice how to have a bit of a chocolate egg surprise in my cupcakes, instead of some melted chocolate 'cream'.

[image]

Comment: Surely the source of that image should mention whether they retain their shape or melt? Or are you wondering if the temperature inside the cupcakes will be higher?

Comment: The images were taken from Pinterest, but I didn't do any reverse image search, like @Catija did apparently. As shown in all images, especially the first, the solid chocolate egg keeps it appearance. What I notice from the comments is freezing the eggs is key to keep them their appearances?  A little side note: Do you need special eggs or any frozen chocolate one will do? That at least gives a smart insight. Thanks

Comment: Removing discussion. It's clear that it's *possible* to put the chocolate eggs inside a baked cupcake. The question is about details: do the eggs need to be frozen, do they melt into the cupcake below what you can see there, and so on, do only some kinds of eggs work, and so on.

Comment: A few example links were supplied in now-deleted comments, including what appears to be [the original source for the image in the OP](http://www.recipebyphoto.com/cadbury-egg-filled-cupcakes/) and  [one that mentions freezing](http://www.lovefromtheoven.com/2012/03/08/cupcake-creativity-four-kinds-of-cupcakes-from-one-mix/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the chocolate melts will depend on which chocolate you use. One with more cocoa butter will melt, while one made with more soy lecithin will retail its shape. That is why most chocolate chips contain soy lecithin. You will need to choose your chocolate according to what you want it to do in the oven.